# Setting break points in z390 Portable Mainframe Assembler and Emulator?

Tags: assembly, mainframe, zos

I've been using the old Dos version of Assist and would like to use the z390 Portable Mainframe Assembler and Emulator instead. I'm able to compile and run programs but am not clear on how to set break points. For example in assist given the following section of an assembly listing

```
000006 5020C03A                00003C       (1/21)21  ST R2,SqrtPCB
00000A 4510C012                000014       (1/22)22  BAL R1,Sqrt
00000E 5880C03E                000040       (1/23)23  L R8,SqrtPCB+4
000012                                      (1/24)24 * END OF YOUR PROGRAM
000012 07FE                                 (1/25)25         BR    14
```

In Assist I can do a b followed by s then enter E for the address. Hitting g to go will then run the program up to the point of loading register 8. When using the Z390 emulator I can run with the test option which provides an interactive prompt. All the commands for setting breakpoints appear to require a condition to be met, I would like to have the program break when it reaches the instruction at address E regardless of the condition. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the address command with the proper base. For example assuming you want to break on the instruction with address E in your listing file and your using statement is

```
USING *,12
```

you would enter

```
a *+E.
```

When using Assist the base reference is automatically added to your breakpoint. When using Z390 the base is not automatically added in.